# Gradle/Maven/Android: Library-private dependency not found when library is used via maven

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependency-management

I have a SampleApp with a library module attached:

```
:app
:library
```

The library is using the following dependency and the following code:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.1"

----

import android.content.Context
import com.google.android.gms.safetynet.SafetyNet

class ClassUsingSafetynet {
    fun trigger(context: Context) {
        SafetyNet.getClient(context)
    }
}
```

The SampleApp is calling `trigger` somewhere:

```
val triggerClass = ClassUsingSafetynet()
triggerClass.trigger(context)
```

This works without problems as long as the SampleApp declares its dependency directly on the library module:

```
implementation project(path: ':library')
```

But if I deploy the library aar to my local maven and declare the dependency accordingly like this:

```
implementation ('com.myapplication:library:1.0.3@aar') { transitive = true }
```

I get the following crash

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNet;
        at com.library.ClassUsingSafetynet.trigger(ClassUsingSafetynet.kt:10)
        at com.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:38)
```

---

Here is the publish gradle task:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {

                groupId 'com.myapplication'
                artifactId 'library'
                version '1.0.3'
                artifact 'build/outputs/aar/library-release.aar'

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                    configurations.api.allDependencies.each {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have tried to use `api` instead of `implementation` for the SafetyNet dependency. No difference.

I have tried to set/not set `{transitive = true}`. No difference.

I have tried to set/not set `@aar`. No difference.

I have tried to not create the pom file. No difference.

No ProGuard is applied for now.

---

What's especially strange to me is that "SafetyNet" is a private dependency of the library. My app doesn't even need to know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The published POM file needs to declare all runtime dependencies of the library, not just its API dependencies. In other words, you need to use the following when adding dependencies to the POM:

```groovy
    configurations.releaseRuntimeClasspath.allDependencies.each {
        // …
    }
```

The following is a misunderstanding:

> "SafetyNet" is a private dependency of the library. My app doesn't even need to know about it.

Your app should indeed not have to worry about this “private dependency” but it still has to (be able to) make it available to the library at runtime – as the library doesn’t work without it because it still is a *dependency* of the library.

I’ve successfully tested this change with a small dummy Android project. Let me know if you can’t get your build to work with the above information; then I can add a self-contained, working sample project to my answer.

---

That said, I wonder why you manually (a) specify the published artifact and (b) create the POM? The following should work automagically (tested as described above):

```groovy
    release(MavenPublication) {
        groupId 'com.myapplication'
        artifactId 'library'
        version '1.0.3'

        from components.release
    }
```

See also [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin).

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reaction and thank you for your answer. I will test this out next week as I have to focus on other topics right now. I will get back here asap.

Comment: hi, just tried it, but it seems like `configurations.runtimeClasspath` is only available for java projects - not for android. I get the message `Could not get unknown property 'runtimeClasspath' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.`. I googled a bit and it seems like `runtimeClasspath` is only available in the gradle java plugin which does not work with Android. [https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html]

Comment: I’m sorry, you’re right. I’ve updated my answer to make it work with an Android library, too. The relevant configuration there would probably be `releaseRuntimeClasspath`. But note that usually it shouldn’t even be necessary to manually fiddle with the POM creation; I’ve added a corresponding note to my answer, too.

Comment: nice!! It finally works as expected. Even the shorthand version with `from components.release`, but for that to work, I had to remove the line `artifact 'build/outputs/aar/crypto-release.aar'`. Otherwise I would've gotten the error: `multiple artifacts with the identical extension and classifier ('aar', 'null')`. Thanks a lot, bounty is yours :)